# Finding minimum required points to represent a polyline from n points in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a binary image that showing the line as white in the image. I have all the coordinates points of the white pixels with me. I want to find the minimum points required to represent that polyline from these n points. How can I do that? Please give me help.

[image]

As you can see in the image, to represent this V image we just need three points. But I got coordinates of all the white pixels. So how can I get the minimum points to represent these kinds of images? This is a sample image. The images can vary to a curved line also. Please Help me with this problem.

Comment: get 3 points: 1 - top left [first x, top y], 2- top bottom [bottom y], 3- top right [last x, top y]

Comment: Do you ever have 'closed' figures (like a triangle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for showing interest in my question. Luckily I got the solution. Python has a library called rdp for doing this.
[rdp](https://pypi.org/project/rdp/)
 So this library will give the minimum points to represent a line where we can specify the tolerance(it is called epsilon here).

```
minPoints = rdp(whitePixelArray,epsilon=1)
print(minPoints)
```

Here the whitePixelArray has the coordinates of all the white pixels in my image. we just call rdp with epsilon=1 and the resultant minPoints has only 6 points.

[image: This is the output in the python shell]

As you can see in the picture the above array is my input and the array below is the resultant array after the rdp operation. Please note that these coordinates are not of the Image which I posted in my question (Sorry for that).

Answer (score 1):

**This is an incredible hacky answer, I welcome any better solutions**

So, we start off with this image:

[image: White V on black background]

I read this file and get all the white pixels using:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.png')
pix = im.load()
width,height = im.size
values = []
for w in range(width):
    for h in range(height):
        if sum(pix[w, h]) > 255 * 1.5:
            values.append((width - w, height - h))

X = [[i[0]] for i in values]
y = [[i[1]] for i in values]
```

Scattering this results in:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Blue V on white background]

Now comes a lot of code I wrote for another project, I'm not going to explain how it works, but you can find the original code [here](https://gitlab.com/nathan_vanthof/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from numpy import median, array


class DecisionTreeError(Exception):
    pass


class DecisionTreeLinearNodes:

    def __init__(self):
        self.decisions = None

    def fit(self, X, y, min_R2):
        self.decisions = {}
        X = array(X)
        y = array(y)
        self._fit(X=X, y=y, min_R2=min_R2, decisions=[])

    def _fit(self, X, y, min_R2, decisions):

        clf = LinearRegression()
        clf.fit(X, y)

        if clf.score(X, y) > min_R2 or len(X) <= 3:

            self._add_decisions(decisions, (X, y))
        else:
            try:
                x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, split_param = self._split(X, y)
                if min(len(x_1), len(x_2)) == 0:
                    raise DecisionTreeError
                print(split_param, len(x_1), len(x_2))
                self._fit(X=x_1, y=y_1, min_R2=min_R2, decisions=decisions + [(split_param, True)])
                self._fit(X=x_2, y=y_2, min_R2=min_R2, decisions=decisions + [(split_param, False)])
            except DecisionTreeError:
                print("Couldn't find a better fit")
                self._add_decisions(decisions, clf)

    def _split(self, X, y):
        best_r2 = 0
        best_param = None
        best_val = None
        for split_param in range(len(X[0])):
            lst = X[:, split_param]
            val = self._get_val(X, y, lst)
            if val is None:
                continue

            choices = lst >= val
            not_choices = lst < val

            x_1 = X[choices]
            y_1 = y[choices]
            x_2 = X[not_choices]
            y_2 = y[not_choices]

            if len(x_1) > 0:
                l1 = LinearRegression()
                l1.fit(x_1, y_1)
                acc1 = l1.score(x_1, y_1)
            else:
                acc1 = 0
            if len(x_2) > 0:
                l2 = LinearRegression()
                l2.fit(x_2, y_2)
                acc2 = l2.score(x_2, y_2)
            else:
                acc2 = 0

            acc = max(acc1, acc2)
            if acc > best_r2:
                best_r2 = acc
                best_param = split_param
                best_val = val

        if best_param is None:
            raise DecisionTreeError("No param fit")

        indexes = X[:, best_param] >= best_val
        indexes_false = X[:, best_param] < best_val
        return X[indexes], X[indexes_false], y[indexes], y[indexes_false], (best_param, best_val)

    def _get_val(self, X, y, lst):
        if len(set(lst)) > 2:
            val_guess_1 = median(lst)
            choices = lst >= val_guess_1
            not_choices = lst < val_guess_1

            x_1 = X[choices]
            y_1 = y[choices]
            x_2 = X[not_choices]
            y_2 = y[not_choices]

            l1 = LinearRegression()
            l1.fit(x_1, y_1)
            l2 = LinearRegression()
            l2.fit(x_2, y_2)

            predictions1 = l1.predict(X)
            predictions2 = l2.predict(X)

            errors1 = (y - predictions1) ** 2
            errors2 = (y - predictions2) ** 2

            prefered_choice = [0 if errors1[i] < errors2[i] else 1 for i in range(len(errors1))]
            lst_vals = sorted(list(zip(lst, prefered_choice)))
            total_1s = sum(prefered_choice)
            total_0s = len(prefered_choice) - total_1s
            seen_0s = 0
            seen_1s = 0
            val = 0
            best_score = 0

            for i in lst_vals:
                if i[1] == 0:
                    seen_0s += 1
                else:
                    seen_1s += 1

                score = seen_1s + total_0s - seen_0s
                if score > best_score:
                    best_score = score
                    val = i[0]

            if val == min(lst) or max(lst):
                return val_guess_1

            return val

        elif len(set(lst)) == 2:
            return (min(lst) + max(lst)) * 0.5
        else:
            return None

    def _add_decisions(self, decisions, clf):
        decisions_dict = self.decisions
        for decision, bool in decisions[:-1]:
            if decision not in decisions_dict:
                decisions_dict[decision] = {True: {}, False: {}}
            decisions_dict = decisions_dict[decision][bool]
        if len(decisions) > 0:
            decision, bool = decisions[-1]
            if decision not in decisions_dict:
                decisions_dict[decision] = {True: {}, False: {}}
            decisions_dict[decision][bool] = clf
        else:
            self.decisions = clf
```

Now, using this we can group the code into straight lines:

```
decision_tree = DecisionTreeLinearNodes()
decision_tree.fit(X, y, min_R2=0.6)
```

I used 0.6 because that seemed to work, you may need to tweak this. To get the groups the tree groups them in, I used:

```
def flatten_array(array):
    x = [i[0] for i in array[0]]
    y = [i[0] for i in array[1]]
    return sorted(list(zip(x, y)))

def get_arrays(decision_tree):
    arrays = []
    for j in decision_tree.values():
        for i in [True, False]:
            if isinstance(j[i], tuple):
                arrays.append(flatten_array(j[i]))
            else:
                arrays += get_arrays(j[i])
    return arrays

arrays = get_arrays(decision_tree.decisions)
```

> I warned you this was hacky ;)

Now we can get a list of points which describe each of the groups:

```
points = []

for i in arrays:
    points.append(i[0])
    points.append(i[-1])
```

However, if you do this, you'll have 'extra' points where one group starts and the other ends. You can remove these using (yet another hacky solution):

```
def get_distance(point1, point2):
    return ((point1[0] - point2[0]) ** 2 + (point1[1] - point2[1]) ** 2)**0.5

def remove_unnecesary_points(points, min_distance):
    to_delete = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
            distance = get_distance(points[i], points[j])
            if distance <= min_distance:
                to_delete.append(j)
    return [points[i] for i in range(len(points)) if i not in to_delete]

points = remove_unnecesary_points(points, 100)
```

I used 100 because that 80 seems to be the thickness of your line, so it should be enough for the worst case scenario. Now plotting this:

```
for i in arrays:
    plt.scatter([j[0] for j in i], [j[1] for j in i])

plt.scatter([i[0] for i in points], [i[1] for i in points])
plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image: V with orange and Blue, Green dots on the corners, white background]

Here orange is one group, blue is another and the green dots show the three points. To finally get the **number** of points required, use:

```
print(len(points))
>>> 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro I got the solution from a library.

Comment: @Blaze could you post that as an answer so others may use it in the future?